# Microsoft Graph APi not returning "Cancelled" Events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all the events in a Conference room's calendar with Microsoft graph API, given a startDateTime and endDateTime. I tried the following API's -

```
1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/events?startDateTime=2017-03-20T05:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-04-06T21:00:00.0000000
2.https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-03-20T05:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-04-06T21:00:00.0000000
```

The response includes all events with isCancelled=false. How do I fetch events which were Cancelled?

`&$filter=isCancelled%20eq%20true` also returned empty as there are no events with `isCancelled=true` in response

Comment: I haven't found any documentation on it, but I am experiencing the same thing. Only non-cancelled events are returned, so the ``isCancelled`` property is always ``false``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, when an event is canceled, it is deleted from the calendar.  So, there isn't a way today to query list of events that are deleted.  We have an item in our backlog for supporting deleted events, but no timeline.

Comment: By the way...I just got an update from my peers that the Cancelled events have started to appear in the response with isCancelled="true"

Comment: @smitesh How are you querying to get the canceled events back?

Comment: that events with isCancelled = true are just events, that have not been deleted, but just canceled by user. MS Calendar API still does not support fetching DELETED events

Comment: i also tried to get canceled or deleted events. the API still doesn't support two of them, even without any filters. they are gone from the response.

Comment: @Venkat,   Could you please advise whether this implemened in 2020. I am trying to get the canceled calendar event but NO LUCK.  please advise

Comment: Hi Guys, does anyone know if Microsoft provided any way to dealt with above issue. I am on same boat but seems like no appropriate way to get details of deleted events.

Comment: Same here @Venkat, we need to get the deleted items in order to retrieve the iCalUid of deleted events. Is that item still in backlog?

Comment: Same on my side, an update would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/xx/Calendar/Events/xx/instances
?startDateTime=2020-02-17&endDateTime=2020-03-01&isCancelled=true
```

and what came back are all the non-cancelled events...
Ditto isCancelled=false

leaving off the &isCancelled=xx parameter returns all the events with the isCancelled attribute set to false for everything.

Comment: I have tried the same but no luck, The MsGraph still sending all the events except the Cancelled event. any advice?

Comment: It's ugly but you could manually create the full series of expected events by looking at the Event.recurrence object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/patternedrecurrence?view=graph-rest-1.0) and then matching your list against what Graph returns and see where the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fetch event after getting notification when event cancelled. I am trying with notification resource url and it throws exception:
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorItemNotFound.
What I was expecting that response with notfound status code rather than throwing exception.

My code for fetching event:

```
var request = new EventRequest(
                    $"{_graphClient.BaseUrl}/{notification.Resource}",
                    graphClientApp,
                    null);

                var message = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                var response = await message.GetResponseObjectAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the beta API, you can use it to get cancelled or modified events for a master recurring event. You can make the following request(make sure to add `$expand=exceptionOccurrences` query string at the end):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=?$expand=exceptionOccurrences
```

You can find the cancelled items in `cancelledOccurrences` which will be of the format `<id>-<date>` and you can probably use the date to figure out which one was deleted. The modified instances are in `exceptionOccurrences`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('d1a2fae9-db66-4cc9-8133-2184c77af1b8')/events(subject,start,end,occurrenceId,exceptionOccurrences,cancelledOccurrences)/$entity",
  "@odata.etag":"W/\"y53lbKh6jkaxHzFwGhgyxgAAw5zhug==\"",
  "id":"AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=",
  "subject": "Daily stand-up",
  "cancelledOccurrences": [
     "OID.AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=.2020-04-30",
     "OID.AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=.2020-05-07",
     "OID.AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=.2020-05-14"
    ],
  "occurrenceId": null,
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-04-23T11:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
  "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-04-23T12:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
  "exceptionOccurrences": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADM0ZGRhMjdjLTA==",
            "Subject": "SM update 24",
            "occurrenceId": "OID.AAMkADAGAADDdm4NAAA=.2020-05-21",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2020-05-21T11:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2020-05-21T12:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-4-expand-a-series-master-event