# Microsoft Graph - Deleted Events from deleted Items folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking to return all calendar events that are in the Deleted Items folder.

Currently I am using the call:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/{deletedItems-id}/messages`

But this only returns the deleted messages. Is there any call available that will allow me to retrieve the deleted events? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to query all events and filter on the `isCancelled` property and optionally add `startDateTime` and `enddatetime` to limit the search.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=isCancelled eq true`

Also, I also tested querying the deleted messages folder and I am seeing items in there that look like the following (note the type and `meetingMessageType` properties). Are you seeing something similar in your queries?

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"DQAAABYAAACuuXbTGFIVS6y5orm951W8AAAUik5T\"",
    "id": "AAMkA...=",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-07-10T20:13:57Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-07-10T20:13:59Z",
    "changeKey": "DQAA...",
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2017-07-10T20:13:57Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2017-07-10T20:13:56Z",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "internetMessageId": "<SN2PR00MB012...>",
    "subject": "Canceled: test cancelled event",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "high",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkADYwODg0MWJiLTQ...=",
    "conversationId": "AAQkADYwODg0MWJiLTQ...=",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/...",
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "meetingMessageType": "meetingCancelled",
}
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for your response. Unfortunately your answer doesn't provide me with what I'm exactly looking for. This only shows me cancelled events. When you delete an event from the calendar it goes to the Deleted Items folder in Mail. So I need to read the events from there. I can read deleted messages but have not found a way to read events. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question : '[Microsoft Graph APi not returning "Cancelled" Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182544/microsoft-graph-api-not-returning-cancelled-events)'

With the response of :

> By design, when an event is canceled, it is deleted from the calendar. So, there isn't a way today to query list of events that are deleted. We have an item in our backlog for supporting deleted events, but no timeline.

Comment: Any updates on the possibility to query removed events ?